# Edit an email before sending

Tags: asp-classic, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

My application uses following function to send email.

Function SendHTMLEMail (strFrom, strTo, strCC, strSubject, strBodyHTML)
 ' create NewMail object
 Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")

' set sender and recipients (latter can be ';' separated lists)
 objNewMail.From = strFrom
 objNewMail.To = "abc@xyz.com"
 objNewMail.Cc = "def@stu.com"

' set Email Subject
 objNewMail.Subject = strSubject

' construct and set Email's body
 strHTMLStart = "" & strSubject & ""
 strHTMLEnd = ""
 objNewMail.Body = strHTMLStart & strBodyHTML & "
To : " & strTo & "
CC :" & strCC & strHTMLEnd

' set parameters to Normal importance MIME-encoded and HTML-formatted Email
 objNewMail.Importance = 1 '9-low, 1-normal, 2-high
 objNewMail.BodyFormat = 0 '0-HTML, 1-Text
 objNewMail.MailFormat = 0 '0-MIME, 1-Text
 ' send Email now
  objNewMail.Send

' release NewMail object
 Set objNewMail = Nothing

End Function

I do not want the email to be sent automatically. It should open in outlook and allow me to edit it.
Can anyone help me with the change I should put here in the code so that the email opens instead of being sent automatically ?

The data is coming from a classic asp page and the above function is in utils.inc

Comment: Reason I want to do this: The application sends automated email to concerned users. Since the email format is same, we need to add some text before sending email.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that you are processing the mail in the **server** and only sending HTML to the **client** (the web browser).

There is **no possible way** to manipulate a program (Outlook) in the client PC from the server, **unless** you have some piece of software (ActiveX, Add-on, etc.) in the client computer.

That said, you can do this trick

```
response.redirect("mailto:name@hotmail.com?subject=Hello&body=Place body here")
```

This will open the mail program configured in the client (it will depend on how the client PC is configured)
Be aware that you are very limited on the length of subject and body.

*Tested in Firefox 3.6, Chrome and Internet Explorer 8 (it raises a security warning)*